# How do I make another series of buttons appear in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, uibutton

My code currently asks the user to pick between Morning and Evening, and depending on their answer, it'll present two more options. However, the options presented after Morning/Evening question aren't functional. I would like my code to extend the quiz so that, for example, after pressing Evening, then pressing Savory, the code will present Option 1 and Option 2. Here is my current code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct IfElseQuiz: View {
    
@State var isMorning = false
@State var isEvening = false
@State var isSnack = false
@State var isMeal = false
@State var isSavory = false
@State var isSweet = false

    
    
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            if !isMorning && !isEvening {
                HStack {
                    Button  {
                        isMorning.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Morning")
                    }
                   
                    Button  {
                        isEvening.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Evening☀️")
                    }

                }
            }
            else if isMorning {
                HStack {
                    Button  {
                        isSnack.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Snack")
                    }
                    
                    Button  {
                        isMeal.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Meal")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            else if isEvening {
                HStack {
                    Button  {
                        isSweet.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Sweet")
                    }
                   
                    Button  {
                        isSavory.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Savory")
                    }
                }
            }
            

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What are "Option 1" and "Option 2", the things you said you want to show after the user selects "evening" and then "savory"? Are they other views?

Comment: what does aren't functional mean in your question?

Comment: @Stoic yes, they are two new buttons that appear after savory is selected

Comment: @Carrot they don't lead anywhere

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @tail just did, works perfectly! Thank you so much! only one more question, if I wanted to add another series of questions, like another two options after you click "Option 1: Apple", how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional answer requested by the poster.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Content: View {
@State var result = "Start"
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            switch result {
            case "Start":
                HStack {
                    Button  {
                        result = "M"
                    } label: {
                        Text("Morning")
                    }
                    Button  {
                        result = "E"
                    } label: {
                        Text("Evening☀️")
                    }
                }
            case "E":
                HStack {
                    Button  {
                        result = "EveningSweet"
                    } label: {
                        Text("Sweet")
                    }
                    Button  {
                        result = "EveningSavory"
                    } label: {
                        Text("Savory")
                    }
                }
            case "M":
                HStack {
                    Button  {
                        result = "MorningSnack"
                    } label: {
                        Text("Snack")
                    }
                    
                    Button  {
                        result = "MorningMeal"
                    } label: {
                        Text("Meal")
                    }
                    
                }
            case "MorningSnack":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Apple") {
                        result = "MSApple"
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Orange") {
                        result = "MSOrange"
                    }
                }
            case "MorningMeal":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Pancake") {
                        result = "MMPancake"
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Bacon") {
                        result = "MMBacon"
                    }
                }
            case "EveningSweet":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Ice cream") {
                        result = "ESWIcecream"
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Tiramisu") {
                        result = "ESWTiramisu"
                    }
                }
            case "EveningSavory":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Steak") {
                        result = "ESVSteak"
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Pasta") {
                        result = "ESVPasta"
                    }
                }
            //here is extra chaning
            case "ESVSteak":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Medium Rare") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Medium") {
                    }
                }
            case "ESVPasta":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: With Bacon") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: With Seafood") {
                    }
                }
            case "ESWIcecream":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Strawberry") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Chocolate") {
                    }
                }
            case "ESWTiramisu":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Half") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Full") {
                    }
                }
            case "MSApple":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Green") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Red") {
                    }
                }
            case "MSOrange":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Big") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Small") {
                    }
                }
            case "MMPancake":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: 2") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: 3") {
                    }
                }
            case "MMBacon":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Crispy") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Soft") {
                    }
                }
            default:
                Text("").opacity(0)
            }
        }
        Button("Restart Game") {
            result = "Start"
        }
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .padding()
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this case, I would go with switch/case for another chaining with the help of string/enum variable. I added some new code into your provided code.

Try the code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct IfElseQuiz: View {

@State var isMorning = false
@State var isEvening = false
@State var isSnack = false
@State var isMeal = false
@State var isSavory = false
@State var isSweet = false
//added
@State var result = ""

var body: some View {
VStack {
    ZStack {
        //added
        if result != "" {
            switch result {
            case "MorningSnack":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Apple") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Orange") {
                    }
                }
            case "MorningMeal":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Pancake") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Bacon") {
                    }
                }
            case "EveningSweet":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Ice cream") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Tiramisu") {
                    }
                }
            case "EveningSavory":
                HStack {
                    Button("Option 1: Steak") {
                    }
                    Button("Option 2: Pasta") {
                    }
                }
            default:
                Text("").opacity(0)
            }
        }
        else if !isMorning && !isEvening {
            HStack {
                Button  {
                    isMorning.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Morning")
                }
               
                Button  {
                    isEvening.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Evening☀️")
                }

            }
        }
        else if isMorning {
            HStack {
                Button  {
                    //added
                    result = "MorningSnack"
                    isMorning.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Snack")
                }
                
                Button  {
                    //added
                    result = "MorningMeal"
                    isMorning.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Meal")
                }
                
            }
        }
        else if isEvening {
            HStack {
                Button  {
                    //added
                    result = "EveningSweet"
                    isEvening.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Sweet")
                }
               
                Button  {
                    //added
                    result = "EveningSavory"
                    isEvening.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Savory")
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: works perfectly! Thank you so much! only one more question, if I wanted to add another series of questions, like another two options after you click "Option 1: Apple", how would I go about it?

Comment: That is super easy. You can handle all your conditions even 100 more chaining with this switch{} statement. Let's say if a user click on "Steak" button, then you assign a new value to result = "EveningSavorySteak" or "Steak, then in your switch{} statement, add new case "Steak". You can keep adding new cases to any number, but don't forget to assign the value to result variable whenever the button is clicked.

Comment: real quick actually, how would that look in the else if statements? would I have to add a new else if block or would I just expand the pre-existing ones?

Comment: since you have such a long chaining, I recommend you go with the switch{} because it was originally made for long chaining. you can actually erase all your old code/condition, and rewrite it with just switch{} + result variable. if you wanna see how it looks in if else{}, basically you have 4 outcomes now, which mean you need to add 4 if else{} , these if else{} should be put at the top before other if else{}. if result == "steak"{} else if result == "ice cream"{}...

Comment: would you mind showing me how the switch{} + result variable style would look with the original code erased and the code going one more chain?

Comment: sure. I added 1 more answer for you in this post.